# Azure Topic Subscription Subscriber

Tags: azure-servicebus-topics

I have a topic and 2(possibly more) subscriptions setup in Azure environment. I plan to have my workers auto-subscribe to the subscriptions. For management purposes, I need to track "active" subscription. Is there anyway to get subscriber count from a subscription?

I got the sample codes which use NamespaceManager. It gets some information on the Subscription, however not the information I needed.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to get subscriber count from a subscription?

`NamespaceManager` can return all the subscription queues created (subscriptions), but it won't tell you if there's a single or scaled out subscription client (listener/processor).

If you're looking into number of auto-scalled subscribers, you're looking at this from a wrong perspective. Auto-scaling is happening (I presume) based on the queue length.

Comment: what I'm building is a job queue with workers. The workers pool will grow accordingly, however not via auto-scaling but manually. Each one of these worker is actually a VM equipped with automation library such as( Selenium and BWS). I CAN write additional logic to wire-up subscriber with a socket service. I was just wondering if azure service  already got something similar.